# How to compare enzyme levels of 8 infected patients with that of 200 normal subjects?

Tags: sample-size, unbalanced-classes

I wish to find out how significantly the enzyme levels of 8 infected patients differ from 200 normal subjects.

1) can i go with unpaired t test with unequal variances?

2) how to nullify the effect of large difference in sample sizes?

Comment: Why do you think that large difference in sample sizes is a problem?

Comment: I think small sample size (e.g. 8 in this case) produces a mean (and variance) which not "representative" of true mean of population...